# Navigation Routes Controller issue in Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC4 Nuget package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

Using the Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC4 is it possible to pass "null" to the **Customer controller** in the ExampleLayoursRoute.config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapNavigationRoute<HomeController>("Home Page", c => c.Index());

        routes.MapNavigationRoute<CustomerController>("Customer", null)  <-- pass null here
              .AddChildRoute<CustomerController>("List", c => c.Index())
              .AddChildRoute<CustomerController>("Add", c => c.Create())
            ;
    }
```

I get an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in the NavigationRouteconfigureationExtensions.cs file:

```
  public static NamedRoute ToDefaultAction<T>(this NamedRoute route, Expression<Func<T, ActionResult>> action,string areaName) where T : IController
    {
        var body = action.Body as MethodCallExpression; <--- Error here
```

You can't add a link to the same controller/action:

```
        routes.MapNavigationRoute<CustomerController>("Customer", c => c.Index())
              .AddChildRoute<CustomerController>("List", c => c.Index())
```

Or you get the error: {"A route named 'Navigation-Customer-Index' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.\r\nParameter name: name"}

My only workaround so far, is to add a second duplicate Action in the controller, and name it Index2 (for example):

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Customers.Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name).ToList());
    }

 public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        return View(db.Customers.Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name).ToList());
    }
```

Is there a better way, than duplicating code, or adding unnecessary actions?

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem to be the statements in Global.asax file:

```
    BootstrapSupport.BootstrapBundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
        BootstrapMvcSample.ExampleLayoutsRouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BootstrapSupport.BootstrapBundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
        BootstrapMvcSample.ExampleLayoutsRouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Due to installing 1.09 and uninstalling the Twitter Bootstrap Nuget package, I found the entries in Global.asax file to be repeated. Removing these duplicate entries worked. You need at least one entry for these 2 calls.

Answer (score 0):

Go to NavigationRouteConfigurationExtension.cs. Find a better way than this, but this hack should make it work (its just a proof). Problem is adding two routes with the same name and the name is generated from route, not display name.

```
    public static NavigationRouteBuilder AddChildRoute<T>(this NavigationRouteBuilder builder, string DisplayText, Expression<Func<T, ActionResult>> action,string areaName="") where T : IController
    {
        var childRoute = new NamedRoute("", "", new MvcRouteHandler());
        childRoute.ToDefaultAction<T>(action,areaName);
        childRoute.DisplayName = DisplayText;
        childRoute.IsChild = true;
        builder._parent.Children.Add(childRoute);

        //builder._routes.Add(childRoute.Name,childRoute);
        builder._routes.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), childRoute);

        return builder;
    }
```